# javascript validation on text boxes created dynamically

Tags: javascript, forms, input, validation

In a form a text box is created dynamically by clicking on add button such that the text box is created in a new row.Now my problem is the validation of text boxes which were created dynamically such that it shows a message if any of text boxes are left empty when form is submitted by clicking submit button.Please help me out.

**EDIT**

```
  <html>
   <head>

  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
   function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
 }

   </SCRIPT>
   </head>


   <body>


    <form onSubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)">
   <INPUT type="button" value="Add More Symptom " onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />


    <TABLE id="dataTable" >
      <TR>

        <TD > 
          <INPUT type="text" name="symp[]" /> 
         </TD>
       </TR>
    </TABLE>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="ADD_SUBMIT">
   </form>


  </body>    
  </html>
```

Above is the script to add new textboxes in a new row.
Now i require that when submit button is clicked, each text boxes should be validated whether it is empty or not on client side. The entered values in the text box should not disappear and number of empty text boxes should be same.

Comment: 1. Validation of text boxes client side or server side? 2. show a bit of code  maybe could halp us reply. 3. if client side validation of boxes does not change much either they are created dyncamically or not.

Comment: Here text boxes ,created dynamically, has to be validated on client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the submit event of the form you simply need to collect all input text boxes that you find in the form and pass them into a validation function.

Put this code in the `<head>` section of your page

```
//This function here is only a cross-browser events stopper
stopEvent = function(ffevent)
{
   var current_window = window;

   if(current_window.event) //window.event is IE, ffevent is FF
   {
      //IE
      current_window.event.cancelBubble = true; //this stops event propagation
      current_window.event.returnValue = false; //this prevents default (usually is what we want)
   }
   else
   {
      //Firefox
      ffevent.stopPropagation();
      ffevent.preventDefault();
   };
}

function validateAllInputBoxes(ffevent)
{
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
      if(inputs[i].type === 'text')
         //@Satish, maybe below you wrote by mistake if(inputs[i].value = '') thus all input elements values get cleared out.
         if(inputs[i].value === '') 
         {
            alert("form could not be sent one input text field is empty");
            stopEvent(ffevent);
         }
}
```

and in the the `<form>` tag place the following code:

```
onsubmit="validateAllInputBoxes(event);"
```

Comment: The above code is working but when alert box is entered the older values in the text boxes should not disappear(here disappeared) and number of text boxes created should be same(here all text boxes are reduced to one).Try to show it in the edited code.

Comment: 1st) REPLACE <form onSubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)"> taht is not even cross browser with <form onsubmit="validateFormOnSubmit(event)"> (exactly how I wrote it) and try again! 2nd) There is no reason why the older value should get cleared out with your/mine code we are not touching the value text unless read the comment I added in code.

Comment: Thanks with little modification in your code i got the result that i require.